# How to call child component method in parent component in react Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, parent-child

I am new to React and Typescript. I am trying call a method from one parent component to on change of parent.

parent.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Child1 } from '../components/Child1';
import { Child2 } from '../components/Child2';

const Parent: React.FC = () => {

    function changeValue() {
        console.log("hello");
        //Want to call child2 callme() method here.
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <Child1 changeValue={changeValue}/>
        <Child2/>
      </div>
  );
};
export default Parent;
```

Child1.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const Child1: React.FC = (props) => {
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState(
    'let name; \n' + 'let age; \n' + 'name = 5;'
  );
 function callMe() {
   //Do something
 }

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        id="details"
        name="details"
        value={props.data}
        onChange={() => changeValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I saw some stackoverflow answers, but was not able to figure out How to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote parent twice in you question. Is your question :
"I am trying call a method from a parent component on change of one of its children component." ?

Comment: You can achieve this using a `ref` (see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), however it's considered an anti-pattern (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159422/is-it-anti-pattern-to-call-child-components-method-from-parent-in-react-and-why) and there are usually better solutions. What are you trying to achieve by calling this function on the child?

Comment: @MisterOrrange Sorry, I was trying to call child component method from a parent component.